# Boost won't work after configuration of .HTaccess

Tags: caching

### Preliminary data

It seems I've configured .HTaccess right, as required by [the following guide to installing Boost](https://www.drupal.org/node/1459690), But it also seems the module doesn't work.

What I did was to copy my .HTaccess **auto generated rules** from `admin/config/system/boost/htaccess/generator` and paste it exactly instead of the sentence "-------paste the rules right here--------" mentioned above, but I don't know if that was the true intention of the author...

Anyway, the final outcome is this:

```
# RewriteBase /

### BOOST START ###

# Allow for alt paths to be set via htaccess rules; allows for cached variants (future mobile support)   
RewriteRule .* - [E=boostpath:normal]

# Caching for anonymous users   # Skip boost IF not get request OR uri has wrong dir OR cookie is set OR request came from this server OR https request   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|HEAD)$ [OR]   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^/(admin|cache|misc|modules|sites|system|openid|themes|node/add|comment/reply))|(/(edit|user|user/(login|password|register))$) [OR]   
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} DRUPAL_UID [OR]   
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200   
RewriteRule .* - [S=3]

# GZIP   
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} !gzip   
RewriteRule .* - [S=1]   
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{ENV:boostpath}/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html\.gz -s   
RewriteRule .* cache/%{ENV:boostpath}/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html\.gz [L,T=text/html,E=no-gzip:1]

# NORMAL   
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{ENV:boostpath}/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html -s   
RewriteRule .* cache/%{ENV:boostpath}/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html [L,T=text/html]

### BOOST END ###

# Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
# Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
# index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

### Why I'm assuming a problem?

On one hand, Drupal's CRON tells me *Boost installed correctly, should be working if properly configured.* On second hand, while surfing from another browser anonymously, I checked page source (CTRL+U), But didn't the famous message (as HTML note):

> Page cached by Boost @ YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, expires @ YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS, lifetime X hours

Therefore, I assume a problem. Now, as Shawn instructed in the comments below, I turned on the Boost debugger, went to Reports > Recent log messages, and then saw two interesting errors:

**First error:**

```
Array
(
    [cache_this] =>
)
```

**Second error:**

This error is to long to be pasted here, but it seems to do something with Drupal's Autocomplete mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify Boost is working by browsing a page as an anonymous user (e.g. using your browser's Incognito/Private Browsing mode) and looking at the source code of the page. If Boost is working you should see a HTML comment at the bottom of the document that looks like this:

```
<!-- Page cached by Boost @ YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, expires @ YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, lifetime X hours -->
```

Comment: Surfed from IE11 as anon user... It seems that Boost is not working :|

Comment: Also, I can't tell if it's your post's formatting, but some of the important .htaccess rules are also commented out. If that's how it looks in the htaccess file, Boost wouldn't work at all. The formatting has been fixed.

Comment: I testify that the previous input is what the module gave me... I don't know why it didn't gave the full syntax you pasted (or It's just another format?)... Anyway I pasted it in the end of my .HTaccess file... right under FileETag MTime, But from IE11 check it seems that Boost is still not working.

Comment: It should start below `# RewriteBase /` in your site root's .htaccess That's about the extent I can help you troubleshoot. The htaccess rule snippet looks correct.

Comment: You mean that the *** BOOST START *** and all that is under it should come after # RewriteBase / ?

Comment: Correct, the snippet looks good as does its position. Its the same setup I've seen in the various sites I manage with Boost installed. There must be something going on with your setup that's not triggering Boost.

Comment: Shawn, is there anything else you might suggest me to check?

Comment: There's a debug mode that you can turn on @ **/admin/config/system/boost/debug**.

Comment: I've updated the question with more data.

Comment: Update --- Seems that Boost is working but there is an error created at the bottom of each page, and this error damages Google PSI scores: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164309/when-boost-module-is-on-i-keep-getting-this-error-in-bottom-of-all-pages?noredirect=1#comment198080_164309